# how to fi this error in Django, Queryset, filet, Attribute Error, how to improve it?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I can not access the entry in the model, although the entry exists, and it is corrected, it is accessed by such a line in any other views. It works correctly, but it is in this views.py

error in 
`seriess = Series.objects.filter(serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, slug=series_slug)`

error herself

```
watched_serial  = seriess.serial_of_this_series
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'serial_of_this_series'
```

views

```
def mark_and_unmark_this_episode(request, serial_slug=None, season_slug=None, series_slug=None):
    return_dict                             = {}
    data                                    = request.POST
    is_delete                               = data.get('is_delete')
    seriess                                 = Series.objects.filter(serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, slug=series_slug)
    for i in seriess:
        print(i)
    watched_serial                          = seriess.serial_of_this_series
    watched_serie                           = seriess
    minutes_of_series                       = seriess
    user                                    = request.user


    if is_delete == 'true':
        mark_it                             = watched_series.objects.get(user=request.user, watched_serial__slug=serial_slug, watched_serie__slug=series_slug, minutes_of_series__slug=series_slug)
        #m = watched_series.objects.get(user=user, watched_serial=instance.watched_serial)
        mark_it.delete()
        update_profile, created             = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        if not created:
            update_profile.user             = user
            update_profile.series_watched_nmb -= 1
            update_profile.save(force_update=True)



    if is_delete == 'false':
        mark_it_watched, created            = watched_series.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, watched_serial__slug=serial_slug, watched_serie__slug=series_slug, defaults={"user":user, "watched_serial":watched_serial, "watched_serie":watched_serie, "minutes_of_series":minutes_of_series})
        if not created:
            mark_it_watched.user            = user
            mark_it_watched.watched_serial  = watched_serial
            mark_it_watched.watched_serie   = watched_serie
            mark_it_watched.minutes_of_series = minutes_of_series
            mark_it_watched.save(force_update=True)




    return_dict["watched_info"]                 = list()




    product_dict                            = {}
    product_dict["user"]                    = request.user
    product_dict["watched_serial"]          = seriess.serial_of_this_series
    product_dict["watched_serie"]           = seriess
    product_dict["minutes_of_series"]       = seriess
    return_dict["watched_info"].append(product_dict)

    print(return_dict)
    return JsonResponse(return_dict)
```

i have another one view in same page, just what was up obly for upgrade button
but this is content on this page and this

```
serie = get_object_or_404(Series, serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, slug=series_slug)
```

is work, in function this is didn't work

If you take this a line of code from this function
mark_and_unmark_this_episode

```
seriess = Series.objects.filter(serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, slug=series_slug)
```

and pasted in functions post_of_serie then this line of code, whis raise and error will all work! why this is happens?

```
seriess = Series.objects.filter(serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, slug=series_slug)
```

another view

```
def post_of_serie(request, serial_slug=None, season_slug=None, series_slug=None):
    serie                           = get_object_or_404(Series, serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, slug=series_slug)
    title                           = serie.serial_of_this_series.rus_name_of_seriall
    full_path                       = All_Images_Of_The_Series.objects.filter(to_series__serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, to_series__season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, to_series__slug=series_slug, is_poster=True)

    context = {"serie":serie, "full_path":full_path, "title":title,}
    try:
        userr                           = request.user          
        check_button                    = watched_series.objects.filter(user=request.user, watched_serial__slug=serial_slug, watched_serie__season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, watched_serie__slug=series_slug )
        context["check_button"]         = check_button
        context["userr"]                = userr
    except:
        pass
    return render(request, 'series.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete all of the code and leave these 2 lines,

```
seriess = Series.objects.filter(serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, slug=series_slug)
print(seriess)
```

it will output an error in the URL, that is, you accept in your function such parameters as serial_slug, season_slug, series_slug, but you probably send the request via Ajax, and these parameters simply do not, If you did this function with the update of the button, on the main function where you output the content, then in that case everything would work for you! Good luck, of course you are still small in Django's knowledge, but you're going quietly, well done!

Comment: Yes, you're right, deleted everything, I got this error, it was written there that it was forgotten {% static%} and then I already output these parameters serial_slug, season_slug, series_slug and it became clear that there are not any, thank you very much, many geniuses came in, but YOU ARE THE ONLY OF ALL WHO HAVE READ THE QUESTION, AND DESCRIPTION, THANKS!